# Generic repository using map

Tags: java

I have a homework that specifies to add to an existent project a generic repository layer. The problem that i face is the following. My repository should encapsulate a map that stores the data. What I have until now is the following:

```
public interface IDObject<T> {
    public Comparable<T> getID();
}

public class Person implements IDObject<String> {
    private String cnp;
    private String name;
    private String age;

    public Person(String cnp, String name, String age) {
    this.cnp = cnp;
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    }

    public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }
    public void setCNP(String cnp) { this.cnp = cnp; }
    public void setAge(String age) { this.age = age; }
    public String getName() { return name; }
    public String getCNP() { return cnp; }
    public String getAge() {return age; }
    public String toString() { return cnp + "-" + name + "-" + age; }
    @Override
    public Comparable<String> getID() { return getCNP(); } //basically the unique identifier
}

public class Repository<T extends IDObject<?????????>>{
    private IMap map;
    public Repository() {
        map = new Map<???????, T>();
    }
    ...
}
```

So my problem appears in Repository class. I want to store persons so I will do something like `Repository<Person> repo = new Repository<Person>();` But the problem is I don't know how to construct the map in the Repository constructor. In other words I don't know the type of the key. I want the Person's `cnp` to be the key(which is of Type `String`), but if I force the map to define the keys as Strings, my repository is no longer generic, because if I want to add some Animal objects that have the key as an integer , the map should be like `map = new Map<Integer, T>();`.

So the question is how can I still use a construction like `Repository<Person> repo = new Repository<Person>();` using the fact that Objects that are stored in a repository implement `IDObject` and knowing that a repository encapsulates a map which stores the data? How should I get to know the key so I can complete the repository class?

Comment: What does a "generic repository layer" really mean? How do you imagine the usage? Will all your deposited objects share unique identifier class? If yes, it should be simple. If no I do not think the task makes sense.

Comment: @Deltharis Well, the repository should have methods like : `store(T obj)`, `getAll()` and so on. For example the `store(T obj)` method will actually make `map.add(K key, T obj)` and will also save the newly stored object into an extern file. Also when you create the repository all the objects stored in the file will be loaded in the map. That's how I imagine a part of the usage. And yes, all my deposited objects share unique identifier class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to introduce another generic type:

```
public class Repository<T, O extends IDObject<T>>
```

After that you can introduce StringIDRepository as

```
public class StringIDRepository<O extends IDObject<String>> extends Repository<String, O>
```

Alternative is to use `Map<Object, O>`, but that would require you to have in your Repository class getById method that takes Object as argument.

Hope this will help!